# Implementing Optimal Crosstalk Cancellation with matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement a crosstalk cancellation in Matlab, more precisely part of : Optimal Crosstalk Cancellation for Binaural Audio with Two Loudspeakers (http://www.princeton.edu/3D3A/Publications/BACCHPaperV4d.pdf).

I am using the matrix H from equation (24) in the paper as my filter and use it as in equation (11). The output does not sound good and has lost all previous "binaural features". Here is a plot of the original binaural signal and the X talk cancelled one :
www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=196157img.png

The binaural sound is a 1000Hz sound wav at the left ear (created with the CIPIC HRTF library). I would have expected the X talk signal to be kind of like the binaural one (where the right channel should be attenuated) but its not the case.

Here is the actual code :

```
%Create binaural sound
aSound = wavread( '1000hz.wav' );
binauralSound = CreateBinauralSound( aSound, pathToHRTF, 1, 9 ); % -90 degree, 0 elevation

%NFFT = 2^nextpow2( length( binauralSound ) );
NFFT = length( binauralSound );

binauralSoundF = fft( binauralSound, NFFT );

theta = 15; %Angle from nose to right speaker in degree
deltaR = 0.15; %Distance between the ears
deltaS = 2; %distance from  ear plane to speaker plane (going through nose);

%Compute ear and speaker position
[speaker1x, speaker1y, speaker1z] = sph2cart( deg2rad(90 + theta), 0, deltaS );
[speaker2x, speaker2y, speaker2z] = sph2cart( deg2rad(90 - theta), 0, deltaS );
lEarx = -1 * deltaR / 2;
rEarx = deltaR / 2;

%Compute distances
l1 =  sqrt( ( speaker1x - lEarx )^2 + ( speaker1y - 0 )^2 );
l2 = sqrt( ( speaker1x - rEarx )^2 + ( speaker1y - 0 )^2 );
deltaL = l2 - l1;
TC = deltaL / 340;
g = l1/l2;

%Filters and parameters
beta = 0.5;
H = zeros( 2, 2, NFFT );
alpha = zeros( NFFT, 1 );
final = zeros( NFFT, 2 );

%Compute value for each freq bins
for k = 1 : NFFT 
    omega = exp( -2 * pi / k );
    %omega = k;
    H( 1, 1, k ) = ( g^2 * exp( i * 4 * omega * TC ) - ( beta + 1 ) * exp( i * 2 * omega * TC ) ) / ( g^2 * exp( i * 4 * omega * TC ) + g^2 - ( (g^2 + beta)^2 + 2 * beta + 1 ) );
    H( 2, 2, k ) = H( 1, 1, k );

    H( 1, 2, k ) = ( g * exp( i * omega * TC ) - g * ( g^2 + beta ) * exp( i * 3 * omega * TC ) ) / ( g^2 * exp( i * 4 * omega * TC ) + g^2 - ( (g^2 + beta)^2 + 2 * beta + 1 ) );
    H( 2, 1, k ) = H( 1, 2, k );

    alpha( k ) = exp( -1i * omega * l1 / 340 )/ l1;

    final( k, : ) = alpha( k ) * binauralSoundF( k, : ) * H( :, :, k );  
end

resultSound = ifft( final, NFFT, 'symmetric');
resultSound( :, 1 ) = resultSound( :, 1 ) / max( abs( resultSound( :, 1 ) ) );
resultSound( :, 2 ) = resultSound( :, 2 ) / max( abs( resultSound( :, 2 ) ) );
```

I am really not sure I am computing H the right way nor I am sure I am applying it correctly. There is not a lot of implementation of crosstalk cancellation on the web so I find it quite hard to find my mistake. I am guessing its something really obvious for all the dsp gurus out there. Your help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your input a 1000 Hz tone? Are you listening on headphones?

Comment: Yes my input is a 1000Hz tone convoluted with a set of HRTF at 90 az, and 0 elevation. I am listening the output with the setup in the code (speaker at 2 meters and 10 degrees inbetween.)

Comment: I don't know anything about crosstalk cancellation but I'm just thinking that a single tone can't convey that much information about a HRTF... Maybe you should try a different sound. What are you expecting to hear? only a tone on one ear? What does your H's functions represent? It looks suspicious that you plug omega into an exponential in you H computation. You have nested exponentials, that looks strange.

Comment: I have also tried with different sound (music for example) and it gives the same result. (www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=274258img2.png)
My H function is actually the filter applied to the signal so it cancels the crosstalk of the speakers. It is the equation 24 from the paper cited above. That is where the exponential comes form. 
Thanks for your help again!

Comment: If I understand correct then $\omega = 2\pi f$ where $f$ is physical frequency in Hz. So $\omega = exp( -2 \pi / k )$ is not correct.

Comment: Another approach is to do the filtering in the time domain. That means going for the impulse responses of the filters.

Comment: As far as I understand the paper, then the H filters are simple models. They don't take into account the effect of the head. So you might not get good performance (cancellation) if any.

Comment: Yes indeed the $\omega$ was wrong. When I used the $2 \pi f$, the ifft yielded weird result, but when using $f$ it seems to kind of work ! As you stated, and as stated in the paper, the cancellation is not perfect since it approximates the interaural delay but it's a start ! I'll continue my readings on that matters. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I took a look at the paper and perhaps I've found something interesting. Eq (25) which you use might be wrong. I'm not sure. But my understanding is that if $\beta = 0$ then Eq (25) should equal the upper left most expression in the matrix in Eq (15). But I'm not sure they are equivalent. Do you agree that Eq (25) should reduce to $\frac{1}{1-g^2e^{-2i\omega \tau_c}}$  for $\beta=0$?

Comment: In fact under Eq (28) is written as $\beta\rightarrow 0$, $\boldsymbol{H}^{\beta}\rightarrow\boldsymbol{H}^{P}$, so can you confirm that the two expression are indeed equivalent?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thanks for your answer again.
Yes I completely agree with you. Since they are mathematically not equal, I have tested both equation and they do not seem to yield exactly the same result as stated by the paper. I am really not sure why though... I thought this would be easier to implement ! If you know a simpler method to do crosstalk cancellation feel free to share it with me ! :)

Comment: I don't have any experience with crosstalk cancellation but I'm slightly interested in this myself. So I don't know how crosstalk cancellation is typically done. Are you doing an educational project? It would be very interesting to know if indeed there is an error in Eq (25). I would recommend that you start by making a very simple simulation by implementing Eq 11 with the C matrix in Eq 7 including alpha.

Comment: Did you solved it? a couple of bugs
1) Do not normalize output left and right with different constants, the two last rows should be similar to: resultSound( :, 1 ) = resultSound( :, 1 ) / max( abs( resultSound( :) ) );
resultSound( :, 2 ) = resultSound( :, 2 ) / max( abs( resultSound( :) ) ); 2) Distance l2 should be refered to speaker2x, speaker2y